# Using Tailwind Elements on Laravel 9

Tags: laravel, tailwind-css, laravel-9

I built a website using Laravel 9 and Tailwind CSS. Right now I want to use the Tailwind Elements library and have followed the instructions on the website, but I'm confused about which file to import `tw-elements` from.

[Source (step 4)](https://tailwind-elements.com/quick-start/)

How to install Tailwind Elements in Laravel 9 (specifically the file where to import `tw-elements`)?

Comment: It says right there in step 3 -> tailwind.config.js

Comment: sorry, i ask for step 4

Comment: does 'TW-ELEMENTS-PATH' refer to the tailwind elements folder in node_modules?

Comment: why don't you just install it from the CDN, much easier, https://tailwind-elements.com/quick-start/#cdn

Comment: If using a cdn, do I have to follow steps 1-3 as before?

Comment: No, you can skip NPM completely and just put the script in the blade template file, then you can immediately start using their components in your blade files. Watch the video https://youtu.be/-GmnyjgI4Jc?t=431 for easier references :D

Comment: Thanks for your advice, its work if i'm using CDN

Comment: Glad it worked! good luck friend :)